# Can I detect via JavaScript whether an image will show the alt text or the broken image picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to load a number images, some will produce a 404 and some requests are aborted.

If I have this:

```
function addImage(my_image_path) {
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onerror = function (evt) {
    console.log("nope");
    console.log(evt);
  };

  img.alt = "COULD NOT DISPLAY IMAGE"
  img.src = some_path_to_image;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Both a 404 and a failed request will trigger the onerror handler and I have no way of differentiating between the cause of the error.

However on the screen I can see the 404 is displayed with the browsers `broken image` while the failed request shows the `alt` text.

**Question**
Is there a way to find out via JavaScript if the browser is defaulting to broken image or alt text? Best before putting putting the image tag on screen.

I have tried `image.complete`, `image.naturalWidth|Height` but that's all of the tricks I know. Maybe someone can chip in with more magic.

Thanks!

Comment: This is browser dependent, so I'm not sure if there's a really reliable way to do it. A quick test just now in recent versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox shows the alt text in all browsers with a 404 image (http://jsfiddle.net/yq8hcaof/). IE and Chrome additionally show a "broken image" icon. If your goal is just to ensure the alt text is always displayed, it seems to be. Alternatively you could detect _any_ error, kill the image tag, and just insert text in its place.